# Can't delete a sql user or connect using correct credentials

Tags: sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008 Express

I created a new database then restored a copy of a database over it. A sql user exists in the database backup so has been added to the database through the restore operation. When I try and delete this user I get:

"The database principal owns a schema in the database, and cannot be dropped"

This is confusing. The user doesn't exist yet, but it owns a schema? Why can't it be deleted?

Next if I add a user with that user name and a valid password, then the user can't even connect to the database.

This has always bugged me, what is the reason and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably because you restored the database and the user was already in that database at the time of backup.  Repair the user-login association with

```
sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'username'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx

also see

http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/sql_orphan_user.htm

Answer (score 4):

`sp_change_users_login` didn't work for me.

But this did:

```
SELECT s.name
FROM sys.schemas s
WHERE s.principal_id = USER_ID('user')
```

Then, take each record listed above and replace `SCHEMA_NAME` with the schema returned with the following statement

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::SCHEMA_NAME TO dbo
```

After I did that for each record, I was able to delete the account.